# Theorem 4.14 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem 4.14

suppose $f$ is a continuous mapping of a metric space  $X$ into a metric space $Y$. Then $f(X)$ is compact.

Proof: let $\{v_{\alpha}\}$ be an open cover of $f(X)$. Since $f$ is continuous . theorem 4.8 shows that each of the sets $f^{-1}(v_{\alpha})$ is open . Since $X$
is compact  there are finitely many indices ,say $ \alpha _1 ,....\alpha _n$ such that:

(12)$\enspace$  $X \subset f^{-1}(v_{\alpha _1})\cup ...\cup f^{-1}(v_{\alpha _n})  $

since $f(f^{-1}(E)) \subset E$ for every $E \subset Y$, (12) implies that

(13) $\enspace$  $f(X) \subset V_{\alpha _1} \cup...\cup V_{\alpha _n}$

I  do i understand  $f(f^{-1}(v_{\alpha _i})) \subset v_{\alpha _i}\enspace(1\leq i \leq n)$ and so on, but not how $f(X) \subset V_{\alpha _1} \cup...\cup V_{\alpha _n}$

Comment: I think it is just using another term to replace $V_{\alpha_i}$

Comment: We generally have $f(A\cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$. So $$f(X) = f(U_{\alpha_1} \cup \dotsc \cup U_{\alpha_n}) = f(U_{\alpha_1}) \cup \dotsc \cup f(U_{\alpha_n}) \subset V_{\alpha_1}\cup \dotsc \cup V_{\alpha_n},$$ where $U_{\alpha_i} = f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_i})$.

Answer (score 2):

You know that

$$X \subset f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_1}) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_n})$$

Let us apply $f$ to both sides.

$$f(X) \subset f\left(f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_1}) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_n})\right)$$

We also know that

$$f\left(f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_1}) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_n})\right) = f(f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_1})) \cup \cdots \cup f(f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_n}))$$

And since you know that $f(f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_i})) \subset V_{\alpha_i}$ you can conclude that

$$f(X) \subset V_{\alpha_1} \cup \cdots \cup V_{\alpha_n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{\alpha_k\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n\}$, then
$$x\in X\stackrel{(12)}{\implies}\exists\alpha\in A,x\in f^{-1}(V_{\alpha})\iff\exists \alpha\in A,f(x)\in V_{\alpha}\iff f(x)\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}V_{\alpha}$$